# How would 8x32 tiles look with one vertical seam on shower walls that measure 39.5“ by 35.5” by 39.5"?

Tags: bathroom, shower, ceramic-tile

I asked this question yesterday with 8x16 tiles, but today I found this tile in a larger size, 8"x32".

The thing is, I made the mistake of putting 2" x 2" tiles on my shower floor of a tile that is hard to match. This being my first tile job, I didn't plan properly.

As said, I found the matching tile in size, 8x32, and they also have the bullnose tiles(3x16). The widths of my shower walls are 39.5" by 35.5" by 39.5".

**How would it look if I had one vertical seam on all three walls?** I know it would be a lot of waste, but that's ok.

The manufacturer says it's a "porcelain tile that looks like marble." The tile is: Gardenia Orchidea Varenna beige.

Thanks! Joe

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  I have installed around 50 showers and designed maybe 5 times that.  You don't buy tile that is just a little shorter than your width.  If you did buy this tile I would run it vertically.

Also I would think if you could possibly extend the edge walls as far as the tile.  You have to think of your shower as a big puzzle.  You want to match the pieces to your shower.  Larger pieces in a small shower are just odd.  It only works well if the pieces match up somehow and in your case they don't.  You are going to spend a lot of time staggering these things to look well.

Really the only thing you could do is a diamond pattern with something that % of the width and that is a really hard install.  Good luck - (buy something that works better).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going to come down to personal opinion.

In general, having just one grout line that is way off center would look a little odd to most people:

```
 ----------------------------------
 |                           |    |
 |                           |    |
 |                           |    |
 ----------------------------------
 |                           |    |
 |                           |    |
 |                           |    |
 ----------------------------------
 |                           |    |
 |                           |    |
 |                           |    |
 ----------------------------------
 |                           |    |
 |                           |    |
 |                           |    |
 ----------------------------------
```

Instead, I'd aim for some sort of pattern. Perhaps staggering them:

```
 ----------------------------------
 |                           |    |
 |                           |    |
 |                           |    |
 ----------------------------------
 |    |                           |
 |    |                           |
 |    |                           |
 ----------------------------------
 |                           |    |
 |                           |    |
 |                           |    |
 ----------------------------------
 |    |                           |
 |    |                           |
 |    |                           |
 ----------------------------------
```

Comment: How about having one vertical seam right down the center of each wall? I'm ok with the waste. **What would look best?** Thanks, Joe

Comment: What would 'look best' is really up to you. I think a center grout line would be OK, but that require twice the amount of cutting on your part. I'm also a fan of saving labor. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the joints appear as if they had a purpose, or totally random.

Purposeful joints would be the type for structure, like the joints you see on a brick wall, whether the joints are centered over the brick above or below or stepped to the side so the joints are stepped by a third of the tile or perhaps a 1/4 of the tile. A pattern more or less that gives the joints purpose. It was also suggested in the lower drawing of DAO1 post.

In my opinion, the tile are too large to make that the best choice, but I could be wrong. I would try a layout on the floor to give it chance perhaps.

Lay out whole tile without cutting any and use cardboard to cover the areas so the visible part is the size of your shower.

My though would be to go totally random by starting with full tile and cutting what you need to finish the run, then use the remainder of the piece that was cut to start the next course, or on the next wall. There will be little waste, and the nature of the install would make the joints totally random. The only thing I would not do random, is do not let the joints fall too closely to each other on the next course above or below any other joints. If you can do this and separate them by 2 tile up or down would help the effect.

I could add a sketch if needed.